# Как такое возможно?

Tags: java, xpath

```
//<Не интересная часть кода, оставлена "на всякий случай">
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(true); // never forget this!
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
org.w3c.dom.Document doc = (org.w3c.dom.Document) builder.parse("/home/danpetruk/strings.xml");
XPathFactory factory2 = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = factory2.newXPath();
//</Не интересная часть кода, оставлена "на всякий случай">

//<Основная часть кода>    
XPathExpression expr2 = xpath.compile("//string/text()");
NodeList vvalues = (NodeList) vvvalues; 
String[] values ={};
for (int i = 0; i < vvalues.getLength(); i++) {
        System.out.println(vvalues.getLength()); //выводит 167 (столько и должно быть)
        values[i] = vvalues.item(i).getNodeValue(); //ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    }
//</Основная часть кода>
```

Ну а теперь вопрос - как в массиве из 167 элементов нету элемента с индексом 0? Ну и заодно - как исправить?

p.s. А вот это почему-то в отличии от первого примера работает:

```
XPathExpression expr1 = xpath.compile("//string/@name/text()");
Object nnnames = expr1.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);;
NodeList nnames = (NodeList) nnnames;
String[] names ={};
for (int i = 0; i < nnames.getLength(); i++) {
        names[i] = nnames.item(i).getNodeValue(); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> String[] values ={};

это инициализирует пустой массив

по поводу второго, там скорее всего nnames.getLength() == 0

Comment: И этот пустой массив я заполняю vvalues -ами

Comment: >это инициализирует пустой массив

Кэп, ты как всегда вовремя. Что бы мы без тебя делали

Comment: замени на new String[nnames.getLength()];

Answer (score 2):

```
package my.test;

public class ArrayTest {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String[] a = {};
        System.out.println(a.length);
        System.out.println(a[0]); // Ошибка
    }
}
```

Пожалуйста не называйте переменные nnnames, nnames, names 
я вас уже ненавижу

Comment: @AlexG212 А чего плохого называть их nnn-слово? Это нам показывает этапы:
1 - nnnames - object
2 - nnames - NodeList
3 - names - String[]

Последний этап - это то, что нам нужно, поэтому мы его и называем нормально. Остальное пришлось использовать для преобразования. Поскольку преобразование разбито на этапы, пусть переменные будут тоже показывать этапы.

p.s. разве массив - переменная?

Comment: могу порекомендовать "Чистый код" т-ща Роберта Мартина.

по ps массив это объект. он где-то в памяти. names это переменная, которая ссылается на массив.